# Trouble Understanding Equivalence Relation Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I'm having a hard time understanding how to show this relation is reflexive:

Let  $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} , Y =  \{3, 4\}$. Define a relation $R$ on the
power set of $X$ by

$A R B$ if $A \cup Y = B \cup Y$

How do I go about showing this is reflexive? The book says its reflexive because $A\cup Y = B\cup Y$

but wouldn't I want to see if the set containing the element of the relation $A R B$ is reflexive? How does this show anything? Furthermore, why do we not check $B \cup Y = B \cup Y$?

Comment: To prove the reflexive property you must show,  for all $A\in \mathcal P(X), A\ R\ A.\  $ $B$ isn't relevant to prove this property.

Comment: How are we able to show the reflexive property when we are using two different sets though?

Answer (score 1):

$A$ and $B$ are dummy set variables here.  The definition says that for any two elements of $X$, which we call A and B and could be the same we have $A\ R\ B$ if and only if $A \cup Y=B \cup Y$.  When you check reflexivity, $A$ and $B$ are the same because you want to prove $A\ R \ A$.  To make sure you understand this relation, you should list the sets that are related to $\{1\}$, those related to $\{3\}$, and those related to $\{1,3\}$

Comment: See I was confused because I thought we couldn't talk about reflexive, transitive, etc if we have 2 different sets. Why are sets A and B the same? how do we know that

Comment: The definition of reflexive says that an element is related to itself.  That means you just have one set you are talking about.

Comment: yea but the problem literally mentions two sets - why does it mention two sets if we only need one?

Comment: The definition of the relation mentions two sets because overall you need to know if two sets are related.  When you ask about whether the relation is reflexive, you plug the same set into both sides.  Compare with the equality relation we know and love.  We can ask whether $A=B$ or not.  To see if it is reflexive, you ask whether $A=A$ for all $A$.  Yes, it does, so equality is reflexive.  It is the same thing here.

Comment: I mulled it over for a second - since the problem mentions reflexivity, we know that A and B have to be the same otherwise we couldn't talk about those properties - right?

Comment: just now saw your comment. I think what I said in my last comment might be wrong. So we are trying to prove in this problem that A = B? My teacher for this course doesn't go much into detail - she just told us the three properties to check for to make an equivalence relation, not so much what it truly means

Comment: No, you haven't understood at all.  I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation carefully.  There are examples there which may help.  You should check whether you understand why the relations given are or are not equivalence relations.  The ones that are not come with explanations why.  The three properties are taken from what we expect from equality and an equivalence relation is supposed to have the important properties of equality/

Comment: I just read through it - my biggest take away was: if a=b then b=a, so equivalence relations exist when talking about congruence. So it makes sense here that it exists, but how can we check that a=b without having the elements of sets A and B?

Comment: You don't have two sets when checking reflexivity.  You only have one.  For *any* $A \subset X$ you have $A \cup \{3,4\}=A\cup \{3,4\}$.  That is all you need for reflexive.  For symmetric you will need two sets (which might be the same) and for transitive you will need three (some of which might be the same).